# Problems putting my game in fullscreen on GameMaker

Tags: game-maker, fullscreen

All the rooms in my game have the size of 1280x720, so normally my game runs like this:

[image]

When I try to enable fullscreen, none of the game's buttons respond to clicks, but the keyboard still works. So in the initial menu I clicked on the button to go to the settings room (**image 1**) and nothing happened, but when I typed "c" on my keyboard went to the settings room:

[image]

[image]

**OBS** - There is a distortion, but not the view in that image (I had to convert **image 3 to jpg**, because in png it was over 2MB in size).

I've thought about switching to **1920x1080** and hiding the **title bar**, but I'd really like to do things the "right way".

---

**EDIT 1** - Another way to enable full screen. (It also does not work)

```js
create event:

window_set_fullscreen(true);
```

**EDIT 2** - By doing a few tests I noticed that when it is in full screen, the clicks behave as if it had a ghost room at the top left of the screen. Like this:

[image]

That is, I click the right side of the word music (in blue) and the language changes.

**OBS** - The buttons in my game are mostly sprites that I mapped and added a **global left pressed** event.

Comment: Not familiar with GameMaker, but is there a chance that you check for clicks based on pixels? Like if click happened between 100 and 200 pixels, music is clicked. If you did that, fullscreen just changes the position of all elements, and for a variety of reasons, its the wrong way of doing things.

Comment: @TomTsagk Correct, I use this artifice so I do not have to create numerous objects to represent the buttons.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why would you need to create multiple objects? Can't you just check the button's dynamic position instead of static pixels?

Comment: To create a button in GameMaker I see two possibilities: 1 - create an object for each button and add an event for each one. 2 - simply through a single object draw sprites and program clickable locations. I can put a part of the code in the question to explain it better.

Comment: What you told me made me think and realized that I can create an obj_Button and replicate it as many times as necessary so that I just need to create a variable to differentiate them and so designate what each one does.
That way, I think it would not be a problem, but the issue is that in some rooms are bigger than the screen, would have to make the buttons walk along with the user's vision.

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with GameMaker, but there should be multiple ways of making the buttons follow the camera. From making the buttons children of the camera, to simply setting their position directly on the screen. Each engine/framework has different ways to deal with that. Also making a separate button object for each button on the screen is the expected thing. Do not try to optimise before your game is ready.

Comment: @TomTsagk "Do not try to optimise before your game is ready." Do not discourage someone from improving their code based on feedback.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso I recall having this issue a while ago as well. I'm trying to remember what the solution was.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Ok so I have a game in front of me right now that seems to work in full screen with buttons and it uses the non-global versions of the events. Try that and see if it works. I don't want to write an answer until I have more details on what happens. (I recall this issue giving me a ton of headaches and the code I'm looking at that does work wasn't a portion written by me).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, I'm not discouraging someone from improving their code based on feedback, I'm saying their code should improve because they probably tried to optimise way too early, and the project sounds like its becoming maintainable. I made multiple comments explaining how to improve the situation and make the code easier to work with.

Comment: I think the solution for the game to work in full screen and in any resolution is to do the layout and defining the locations of each of the images based on the size of the screen. I will be waiting @TheGreatDuck.

Comment: @TomTsagk this issue is the equivalent of calling a built in feature and seeing it doesn’t work. It’s a bug in game maker. I believe it even had a bug submit page for it way back when 8.0 was supported.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso did you try non-global click events? Just change the event. I’m 99% certain that will work. Just making sure it actually fixes before I post an answer.

Comment: @TomTsagk The main controls for game maker objects are done via events which are preset conditions checked each frame which you can then either add code to be executed or a series of drag and drop functions. One of these events is “check clicked” or something to that effect. Not sure what “global” refers to but I’ve never gotten that event to work very consistently... ever, and I’ve been using the software for over 7 years.

Comment: @TomTsagk “Could you elaborate? Why would you need to create multiple objects? Can't you just check the button's dynamic position instead of static pixels?” They don’t have to make multiple objects for one button. Each button is its own object. They aren’t doing the pixel checks. From our perspective it is a built in black box. I am completely against implementing their own version when a perfectly good event does it already for free. If neither of them work then someone needs to link this question to a yo-yo games support staff and tell them they have a ***serious*** bug in their code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The way to detect mouse click was as follows (Global Left Pressed):**

```
if(point_in_rectangle(window_mouse_get_x(),window_mouse_get_y(),1250,690,1280,720)){
    game_end();
}
```

That way it just happened to have a "ghost room" (as I said in the question).

**Just change the click logic to the following (Global Left Pressed):**

```
if(mouse_x>=1250 && mouse_x<=1280 && mouse_y>=690 && mouse_y<=720){
    game_end();
}
```

The problem was exactly how to get the values ​​of **X** and **Y**. Because if you use the function `point_in_rectangle` and use `mouse_x`/`mouse_y` instead of `window_mouse_get_x`/`window_mouse_get_y`, it works as expected.

**Se below (Global Left Pressed):**

```
if(point_in_rectangle(mouse_x,mouse_y,1250,690,1280,720)){
    game_end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **global left press event**, which as far as I know does not work in the manner you desire (screen resizing). Use the non-global version.

If that fails then implement your own click detection code and also contact the creators of Game Maker (shoot them an email) because that should be working and did work with rescaling as of version 8.1 which is only 7 years old. There’s no reason for the event functionality to have changed. That’s bedrock level stuff. Change that on purpose and thousands of games will be reporting bugs so I’d certainly expect the non global to work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I intend to launch the game on Steam before doing anything you suggested. By my calculations on Wednesday having already released the game, I inform you if your answer has solved my problem and milestone as correct.

Comment: You are aware it should take under five minutes to test the fix, right?

Comment: I'm aware, I've already backed up and I just do not start testing now because I'm trying to convert the game to launch also on Android.